# Renamed c# class and now I can't access the public const variables in that class

Tags: c#, class, constants, rename, public

I renamed one of my c# classes and now I can't access the 'public const byte' variables in that class. I renamed it in the solution explorer and when it asked if I would like to perform a rename in the project of all references to the code element 'className' I selected 'Yes'.

The error message I'm getting is: "Member 'Namespace1.Class1.CONSTANT_NUM' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead".

Everything else in the class works (i.e. the methods and non-const fields) but I don't know why I'm not able to access the public const fields any longer?? Any ideas?

Comment: What does *"I'm not able to..."* mean, more specifically? What message is displayed? Does it occur at runtime or compile-time?

Comment: You need to provide more detail. Are you getting an error? If who, what is it? Have you tried going to the files that are giving you a problem and manually fixing the references?

Comment: Can you provide some code? Maybe your renamed class and how you are trying to access one of the `public const byte` members. It'll be easier for us to troubleshoot.

Comment: Possible causes off the top of my head are: you made the entire class non-public, or you are still referring to the old name, or you are referring to the new name from a different assembly and have build sync issues.

Comment: Adding to what Peter said, can u try cleaning and solution and rebuilding.

Comment: I've just added the error message to my question..

Comment: My best guess is: Does the new class name conflict with another name (eg. a namespace name?) That could be confusing the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constant is associated with a particular type, rather than a particular instance (considered static).

Your error message is telling you that you're trying to access a `const` from a particular class instance, rather than a type.

So if your class was:

```
public class Class1()
{
    public const int MY_INT = 5;
}
```

You may well be trying to do this somewhere in your code:

```
Class1 thisInstance = new Class1();
Console.WriteLine(thisInstance.MY_INT); // Will cause an error.
```

What you probably want to be doing is this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Class1.MY_INT);
```

Edit:
It might be the case that before the error, your instance name was the same as your type name, and the compiler couldn't infer what you meant.

Comment: Super!! Thanks so much. You got it spot on! My instance name must have been the same as my type name. Oops. Thanks again!

Comment: Cracking, I thought that might have been the initial cause, because it's something I've done myself and subsequently been very confused =D